# Is it possible to create a BoolProperty on the fly in the panel to control a FloatProperty of a node?

Tags: python, materials, node-editor

Assuming that the nodes have no possibility of boolean buttons, I was wondering if it is possible to draw one on the fly that sets the value 0-1 (Fac) of a `"MIX_RGB"` type node.
Suppose that it retrieves all `"MIX_RGB"` type nodes with an operation of this type:

```
class CustomMenu(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom Menu"
    bl_idname = "Test_PT_menu"        
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Test"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        ob=context.object
        mat = ob.active_material
        if mat:
            for n in mat.node_tree.nodes:
                if n.type == 'MIX_RGB':
                    #I would like to turn this into a Boolean False = 0, True = 1 :
                    layout.prop(n.inputs[0],"default_value",text=n.name)
```

This is what I get if there is a node of type `"MIX_RGB"` in the material:

[image]

[image]

Actually I'd like to get a boolean property, which if True it sets the value to 1, otherwise the value must be 0 .

Since I would like any node of type "MIX_RGB" to show this property, I was wondering if it was possible to create a property on the fly that does this, avoiding to compile an infinite number of BoolProperty in a class of type PropertyGroup, it would be somewhat difficult to predict, for the simple reason that if the nodes were 100, I should have 100 BoolProperty declared. So I wondered if there was a way to create a situation on the fly

Comment: Why not just using a callback on `update` and set all values to `1.0` and `0.0` based on your `true` and `false` logic?

Comment: Excellent question, currently I am able to create a BoolProperty that refers to the material (bpy.types.Material) the problem is that I should declare countless BoolProperty, as it is not known exactly how many nodes of type "MIX_RGB" are present in a material. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you generate those nodes by a script? If so, I'd give them a specific name or store those nodes in a property group when adding them to the scene.

Comment: Nodes are not generated, but can be recognized, but I think I solved it, just create an operator to pass a string argument (with node name, material, and input number) that sets the value to 1 or 0